# react fallback is shown when lazy load WITH preloading

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, flicker

I'm currently trying to resolve a maybe not so react-conform-ish issue. Honestly I've no idea to solve it differently in better way:

#### TLDR;

So actually the question is.. is it possible to AVOID the react lazy load suspense fallback, when the component is preloaded and SHOWING the fallback, when this is not the case or the preload is still in progress?

I also created a little code sandbox, so you could play around with the issue :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-matsumoto-wufcq5

*EDIT:* also the current "solution" is integrated

#### Issue

We have a big set of components, that should get rendered dependently by some provided key - so to avoid the if/else hell, we're using a map object and depending on the provided key the required component gets rendered

```
..

const THE_MAP = {
  test1: reactLazyWithPreload(() => import("./LazyComponent")),
  test2: reactLazyWithPreload(() => import("./LazyComponent2")),
};

const LazyComp = THE_MAP[oneOrTwo]; // oneOrTwo => either "test1" or "test2"

<React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
  {isShowingLazyComponent ? <LazyComp /> : <div>not yet</div>}
</React.Suspense>

..
```

so with this, everything works as expected - the lazy component gets loaded and while loading its showing the fallback

now we've added a helper for lazy load components to be able to prefetch them, as we actually know which one we want to render next

helper:

```
type FactoryType<T> = () => Promise<{
  default: T;
}>;

export interface LazyExoticComponentWithPreload<
  T extends React.ComponentType<any>
> extends React.LazyExoticComponent<T> {
  preload: FactoryType<T>;
}

export const reactLazyWithPreload = <T extends React.ComponentType<any>>(
  factory: FactoryType<T>
): LazyExoticComponentWithPreload<T> => {
  const Component = React.lazy(factory);

  (Component as LazyExoticComponentWithPreload<T>).preload = factory;

  return Component as LazyExoticComponentWithPreload<T>;
};
```

also the preloading works.. at least from a network tab perspective

**BUT** even when preloaded, it still shows the loading fallback component for a split second, which leads to a flicker or "content jump"

is it possible to avoid this without a "height-lock-hack" (we currently save the height of the previous component until the new one is loaded, which feels a little dirty ^^)

also setting fallback to `<></>` or `null` won't do the trick, as it'll still flicker, as it tries to show the fallback for that split second

#### Update

Amin Jafari and I co-riddled on this issue afterwards and we came to the finding, that a `setTimeout` (or `requestAnimationFrame`) around the "change-trigger"

`setOneOrTwo((oneOrTwo) => (oneOrTwo === "test1" ? "test2" : "test1"))`

part from the codesandbox example "solved" the flickering

so it looks like that:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() =>
  setOneOrTwo((oneOrTwo) => (oneOrTwo === "test1" ? "test2" : "test1"))
);
```

My GUESS here is, that React.Suspense actually has no clue about weather the chunk has already been loaded or not, or that the chunk is there but has not been integrated yet (react or webpack issue?)

so with adding the timeout it SEEMS to give the application the time to actually integrate that chunk first and then directly make use of it :S

PLEASE - if anyone has another explanation or thought or solution - let me know, as this is really an interesting behavior